# Learning mobile cloud computing with android app

Tags: android, cloud, cloud-hosting, mobile-application

I just start to learn about cloud computing with mobile device. ( I am currently starting to search about this field)

For part of leaning this field, I would like to learn to build android application which is able to upload data( text file , context information , and picture ) to the cloud computing environment( amazon ec2 or google service)

However, I have no idea where I can start to learn those stuffs.

Does anybody know any tutorial or text book that i can use ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty loaded and broad question, but luckily, there are services that are built to get you up and running with minimal friction. One of my favorites is [StackMob](http://stackmob.com). You can easily create a remote database, and use their Android SDK to sync with it. They also have amazingly simple connection to Amazon S3, to easily allow file uploads.

The best part: It's free for basic usage. They've taken an *à la carte* approach, that allows you to create a full web service, with only the add-ons you need. To simply have a remote database and S3 connection is free.

Start here: https://developer.stackmob.com/start

Comment: Thanks Paul. And I am sorry about loaded and broad question. (I would like to get a job about this field in the future). So, I would like to learn something about mobile cloud computing.I was searching and researching about this field. However, i could not find any good resource to study it..

Comment: @DcRedwing Note: I updated the start link.

Answer (score 0):

One good resource I have found is http://www.firebase.com, it is really good for all around storage of small data on multiple devices, and would work best for things like collaborative drawing apps (as you specified cloud computing (meetings?)) as far as the data storage maybe you could look at implementing ftp, or webdav into a simple application just to start.